# What is needed to access another user's facebook posts ("App Not Setup")

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a desktop app which uses a user access token to read the me/feed endpoint and I can see all the posts for the logged in user.  If I wanted to simplify deployment to different users I would need to minimise the amount of setup/configuration they did.

Is there a way to access me/feed for a given userid rather than have to setup every user as a developer account and create an app for it?

I have looked at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0 and it is not obvious to me how to do this.

What configuration / permissions does the user in question need to do to activate this.  Which access token should I be using, and will it give access to all the posts in the same way the user access token does.

[EDIT]  I have looked at this again and the problem I am having is that when a user (who has a facebook account but is NOT a developer) tries to login to my App (which is in development mode) I get the following error

"App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login."
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why will you need to *setup every user as a developer*? Once a user auth your app you can just do `/me/feed` - will get you the feeds of the user

Comment: From what I understand, me/feed is done in the context of the user access token. So me/feed will only work for one access token.  What should have worked though was doing /<user id>/feed but this will no longer work on apps created after 30 April 2014 - I get (#803) Cannot query users by their username error.  How can I work around this ?

Comment: You seems to be confused. I would recommend you to read the docs and API reference properly.

Comment: I have reread the docs and they dont really help. The initial user taken is created on the developers.facebook.com page and has the userid of the logged in developer bound into it.  If any other user uses that access token the stage where the access token is extended will fail because the user ids are different.  So perhaps what you are saying is that the logged in user creates their own access token for use with the app.  Except that I cannot see a way of doing this.  Or, are you saying that I should be using an App Token ?

Comment: Added more information about the symptoms encountered when trying to login from a non developer account.